# I'm getting data from api and showing on ionic view in input ng-init but fields got disable I'm not able to write anything in fields

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting data from api and showing on ionic view in input ng-init but fields got disable I'm not able to write anything in fields.

Ionicviewcontent.html

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-init="{{data.firstname = Data.first_name}}" ng-model="data.firstname" required="">
</label>
```

controller.js

```
var str = "http://localhost/VivoticCMSApp/php/userview.php?id=" + $stateParams.id;
$http.get(str)
        .success(function (response) {

            if(response !== false){

               $scope.Data = response.userDetail;
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"  ng-model="Data.first_name" required="">
</label>
```

Comment: its working but not send data on click bcoz n-g-model="Data.first_name" is the obj contain on that data which i m getting from api,

Comment: I have also send data to controller this is an edit form and i m showing existing details in input when user edit these details so i want that details.

Comment: if you edit the details in current form if you update it  in controller you will get the data in Data object

Comment: print the console.log($scope.Data) you will get the details here

Comment: thanks bro got it its working now i was passing the old ng model data obj in edit function then i passed api's data obj in edit function now i m getting my new result. Thanks Alot

Comment: always welcome happy coding!.. give me upvote for myanswer